# Asp.Net 5 7.0.0-rc1-final Database First woes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Have an up and running asp.net 5 beta 5 app.

Trying to migrate to 7.0.0-rc1-final.

To create a simple test environment, I create a new ASP.NET Web Application:

```
VS2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00079
```

I run, register, and login.  All working fine.

Then to test database first principles:

Using a copy of the db in use for the beta 5 app, I run:

> dnx ef dbcontext scaffold -c "ApplicationDbContext"  -o "Models"
>   "Server=.\SS2014;Database=TSICV5;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer

The Models folder fills in, app compiles fine.

Runs fine until login which fails on:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

with:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entityType
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
```

Have researched, but no luck.  I'm not well versed in EF7 migrations and could really use a nudge in the right direction.

I'm concerned my Identity Tables in my db are different that what is being assumed (but careful inspection of the createidentitytables migration.cs show the essentials are correct, the only thing I see different is the naming of the keys and the absence of a few indexes)

I'm also curious about the snapshotfile.cs and it's purposes and whether that is a lead.  That file seems to be creating "Identity" equivalents of "AspNet" tables in the database and I wonder if that is the issue.  Not sure where those classes are being stored (metadata?), and whether using db first removes their creation...

Greatly appreciate any pointers or insights.

Todd

Answer (score 0):

You can check and add ApplicationRole to IdentityDbContext generic parameters like as in the following example.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```